# Slyling codename one application using .css text files

Tags: codenameone

A few of months ago I watched this vido [Steve Hanna video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtToUsZekjE).

It describes a good way to apply style in  a "Codename One application" using .css text files. 
Does current version of "Codename One Plugin (3.6)" allow me to do that?
Do I need to install some .cn1lib module to make this feature work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a feature Steve worked on in his spare time and integrated via an extensions which you can install with [these instructions](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/rounded-corners-shadows-and-gradients-with-css.html). We are looking for feedback on this feature and we are trying to gauge the desire to roll it into Codename One proper.

We know a few people use it but we're still looking for feedback.

Comment: I recently read about a new feature that deals with this subject using a similar approach to JQuery that deserves an attention. Details of this new option can be obtained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/jquery-css-style-selectors-for-cn1.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would have written this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

I would be very happy if you adopted Steve's cn1-css plugin into Codename One. I use it every day, and vastly prefer it to messing with the GUI theme/resource editor.

I use a lot of "custom" rounded rectangles with background color, and I'd much rather make a quick edit to a text file (.css) than "start over" in a paint application, divide image into pieces, etc.  CSS is quicker and a *lot* less error prone (for me, at least).

Perhaps I am missing an "obvious" solution to this problem of "I want to try out a different bg color, or a different border radius," or maybe cn1-css *is* this obvious solution?

I am very grateful to Steve for writing this cn1-css plugin!